# How to run a cron job each time the previous execution has finished?

Tags: terminal, python, cron

I would like to run a Python script each time it finishes and I think I can do this with cron but I am not sure how to do it.

The idea is each time the Python scripts ends, it will have to run again and again.

I have searched for answers here but I can't find something similar to this.

Comment: Why not make the script loop rather than exit or make it run when something happens e.g. a directory changes depending on what it is looking for

Comment: The script is used to scraped Google results, so it needs to take some time due to IP overload.

Comment: So it could loop and set launched up to restart it if it crashes (the latter would work even if it ends normally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminal:

```
while :; do ./script_name; done
```

or

```
while :; do python programm.py; done
```

If you want add some sleep time before run program again use 'sleep' command:

For example:

```
while :; do python programm.py; sleep 90; done
```

in this example cycle will sleep 90 second before run again you program

Comment: Do I have to write something like: python programm.py anywhere?

Comment: while [ 1 ]; do python programm.py; done

You may add another commands if you want:


while [ 1 ]; do python programm.py; command2; command3; etc; done

Just split it with ;

Comment: Answer below and my answer it's shell scripting. Bash, sh, etc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks @user3439968 - I have used the third instruction and it works like a charm. That is all I need.

Answer (score 1):

Cron is a scheduler, it's good if you want your script to run every 5 minutes, or every 3rd Wednesday etc, but for an arbitrary restart upon completion which could (I presume, you don't indicate what the Python script is doing, how long it takes or if the time to completion is variable etc) be essentially random it's not the best choice.

You can either insert some logic into the script directly, or you could simply wrap the script with some Shell Scripting logic as per @user3439968's answer, my version is essentially the same, but I've shown it a little more verbose with options for keeping an eye on the restarts etc.  You can type this into pretty much any command line shell, simplest to just open `Terminal` and type it straight into it

```
while true
do
    /path/to/script.py
    sleep 60
    date >> /path/to/logfile.txt
    echo "The script ended, and I restarted it after 60 seconds" >> /path/to/logfile.txt
done
```

In the example above the restart isn't immediate but waits 60 seconds, then appends the current date and a message to a log file on each restart.  You can put any control code after the initial run of the Python script and the `done` line, even get it to mail you that it's restarted etc.

Because you don't specify what "true" is, it can never be false, so essentially everything between `do` and `done` is looped over and over until it receives a suitable interrupt signal like a `CTRL-c` or a `kill -9 PID` type command from another command line session.